# Is it possible to integrate bot-builder into an existing express app?

Tags: node.js, events, botframework

I have an existing node/express chatbot application that connects to several chat platforms using ExpressJS' next(), next() middleware design pattern. I send a 200 response at the very beginning to acknowledge the receipt of a message, and send a new POST request to send a message from my last middleware.

```
app.post("/bots", receiveMsg, doStuff, formatAndSendMsg, catchErrors);
```

Now I want to integrate Skype as a channel for my bot, but the NodeJS library for bot-framework has a totally different way of doing things, using events and such magic that I haven't fully understood yet:

```
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector();
app.post("/skype", connector.listen());
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

It doesn't look like these are compatible ways to do things, so what is the best way to receive a message and then send a response to a user without having to change my express routing to fit bot-builder in? Can I get a Session object with Session.send() to respond to? Will I have to do all the addressing manually? Is there a method that resembles this:

```
app.post("/skype", (req, res, next) => {
    const address = req.body.id;
    const message = new builder.Message(address, messageBody).send()
}
```

Or:

```
app.post("/skype", connector.listen(), (req, res, next) => {
    // (res.locals is available in every express middleware function)
    const session = res.locals.botFrameworkSession;
    // do stuff
    session.send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building messages, addressing them, and sending those messages are all possible using the official bot framework NodeJS library. What I couldn't do with that library was receive messages and verify their authenticity on my routes without making major changes to my design (using request middleware - next() - to process the incoming request) which is already in production with other bots and not easy to change.

Here's my workaround: First is this BotFrameworkAuthenticator class that I create based on the Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication
It is instantiated with the appID and appPassword from your Bot Framework app.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import * as jwkToPem from 'jwk-to-pem';

export class BotFrameworkAuthenticator {
    private appId: string;
    private appPassword: string;
    private openIdMetadata: any;
    // The response body specifies the document in the JWK format but also includes an additional property for each key: endorsements.
    private validSigningKeys: any;
    // The list of keys is relatively stable and may be cached for long periods of time (by default, 5 days within the Bot Builder SDK).
    private signingKeyRefreshRate: number = 432000; // in seconds (432000 = 5 days)

    constructor(appId, appPassword) {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appPassword = appPassword;
        this.getListOfSigningKeys();
    }

    // response data should contain "jwks_uri" property that contains address to request list of valid signing keys.
    public async getOpenIdMetaData() {
        // This is a static URL that you can hardcode into your application. - MS Bot Framework docs
        await axios.get("https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration").then(response => {
            this.openIdMetadata = response.data;
            logger.info("OpenID metadata document recieved for Bot Framework.");
        }).catch(err => {
            logger.warn(err.message, "Could not get OpenID metadata document for Bot Framework. Retrying in 15 seconds...");
            setTimeout(this.getListOfSigningKeys, 15000);
        })
    }

    public async getListOfSigningKeys() {
        await this.getOpenIdMetaData();
        if (this.openIdMetadata && this.openIdMetadata.jwks_uri) {
            // previous function getOpenIdMetaData() succeeded
            await axios.get(this.openIdMetadata.jwks_uri).then(response => {
                logger.info(`Signing keys recieved for Bot Framework. Caching for ${this.signingKeyRefreshRate / 86400} days.`);
                this.validSigningKeys = response.data.keys;
                setTimeout(this.getListOfSigningKeys, (this.signingKeyRefreshRate * 1000));
            }).catch(err => {
                logger.error(err.message, "Could not get list of valid signing keys for Bot Framework. Retrying in 15 seconds");
                setTimeout(this.getListOfSigningKeys, 15000);
            });
        } else {
            // previous function getOpenIdMetaData() failed, but has already queued this function to run again. Will continue until succeeds.
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies that the message was sent from Bot Framework by checking values as specified in Bot Framework Documentation:
     * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication#step-4-verify-the-jwt-token
     * Retrieves the Bearer token from the authorization header, decodes the token so we can match the key id (kid) to a key in the OpenID
     * document, then converts that key to PEM format so that jwt/crypto can consume it to verify that the bearer token is
     * cryptographically signed.
     * If the serviceUrl property in the token doe not match the serviceUrl property in the message, it should also be rejected.
     */
    public verifyMsgAuthenticity(serviceUrl: string, headers: any) {
        try {
            const token = headers.authorization.replace("Bearer ", "");
            const decoded = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true }) as any;
            const verifyOptions = {
                issuer: "https://api.botframework.com",
                audience: this.appId,
                clockTolerance: 300, // (seconds) The token is within its validity period. Industry-standard clock-skew is 5 minutes. (Bot Framework documentation);
            }
            const jwk = this.lookupKey(decoded.header.kid)
            const pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
            const verified = jwt.verify(token, pem, verifyOptions) as any;
            if (!serviceUrl || serviceUrl !== verified.serviceurl) {
                logger.warn("Non-matching serviceUrl in Bot Framework verified token!")
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            logger.warn("Received invalid/unsigned message on Bot Framework endpoint!", err.message)
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Finds the relevant key from the openID list. Does not transform the key.
    private lookupKey(kid) {
        const jwk = this.validSigningKeys.find((key) => {
            return (key.kid === kid);
        });
        return jwk;
    }
}
```

Use the BotFrameworkAuthenticator class like this at the very beginning of your express route to verify that all incoming requests are valid.

```js
const botFrameworkAuthenticator = new BotFrameworkAuthenticator(appID, appPassword);

router.post("/", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (botFrameworkAuthenticator.verifyMsgAuthenticity(req.body.serviceUrl, req.headers) === true) {
        res.status(200).send();
        next();
    } else {
        // unsafe to process
        res.status(403).send();
        return;
    }
});
```

And to send messages using the regular Bot Framework library without having a Session object that would normally be created by the Bot Framework library when it receives an incoming message:

```js
import * as builder from "botbuilder";

// instantiate the chatConnector (only once, not in the same function as the sending occurs)
const botFrameworkSender = new builder.ChatConnector({ appId, appPassword });

//---------------------------------------------

const skypeMsg = req.body;
const address = {
    channelId: skypeMsg.channelId,
    user: skypeMsg.from,
    bot: skypeMsg.recipient,
    conversation: skypeMsg.conversation
};
const response = new builder.Message().text(someText).address(address).toMessage();
const formattedResponses = [response];
botFrameworkSender.send(formattedResponses, logErrorsToConsole);
```

Note that all of the builder.Message() -- .attachment(), .images(), etc.. -- functions can be used, not just the text()

Answer (score 1):

You can register bot application in your existing express applications. Bot builder SDK is also compatible in expressjs framework. You can refer to [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/demo-ContosoFlowers/app.js) which is also leveraging express.

Don't forget to modify the messsaging endpoint in your bot registration to your bot's endpoint, e.g.

```
https://yourdomain/stuff
```

in your scenario. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration for more info.

Comment: What I am really hoping for is a way to get a session object at the beginning of the route, then save it on `res.locals` so that when I am ready to respond I can use `session.send()`.


Something like this:
`app.post("/stuff", connector.listen(), doStuff, moreStuff queryDB, formatAndSendMsg, catchErrors);`

Comment: i don't think you can do like this